# How can I use function callback ('StopFcn' , 'TimerFcn' )for audiorecorder object in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, callback

I want to execute the function 'get_pitch(samples,fs,winsize,winshift)' while during recording through audiorecorder object. To do that, I found that 'function callback' would be helpful to do that.

So I try to this code.

```
% assume fs,winsize,winshift is given.

T = 0.1; % in seconds
samples = cell{100,1};
r = audiorecorder(fs,16,1);
k=1;
r.TimerPeriod = 0.1;
r.StopFcn = 'samples{k} = getaudiodata(r);';
r.TimerFcn = {@get_pitch,samples{k},winsize,winshift};

while 1
     record(r,T);
     k=k+1;
end
```

But following exception occurs during execution.

1) after record(r,T) is executed. (StopFcn is now called)
??? Error using ==> eval
Undefined function or variable 'r'.

2) after StopFcn is called (TimerFcn is now called)
In this phase, get_pitch function have totally wrong parameters. For example, parameter
in the position samples{k} change to 'audiorecorder object'.

It seems that I do not know exact use of 'StopFcn' & 'TimerFcn'.

Is there anyone who can give me some advice? I really appreciate all of your comments.

Comment: The `StopFcn` should be `@(events, data) eval('samples{k} = getaudiodata(r);');`, I think.