# Function callback ('StopFcn' , 'TimerFcn' )for audiorecorder object in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use function callback ('StopFcn' , 'TimerFcn' )for audiorecorder object in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520290/how-can-i-use-function-callback-stopfcn-timerfcn-for-audiorecorder-objec)

So I try to this code.

```
% assume fs,winsize,winshift is given.

T = 0.1; % in seconds
samples = cell{100,1};
r = audiorecorder(fs,16,1);
k=1;
r.TimerPeriod = 0.1;
r.StopFcn = 'samples{k} = getaudiodata(r);';
r.TimerFcn = {@get_pitch,samples{k},winsize,winshift};

while 1
     record(r,T);
     k=k+1;
end
```

I want to execute the function 'get_pitch(samples,fs,winsize,winshift)' while during recording through audiorecorder object.

But following exception occurs during execution.

1) after record(r,T) is executed. (StopFcn is now called) ??? Error using ==> eval Undefined function or variable 'r'.

2) after StopFcn is called (TimerFcn is now called) In this phase, get_pitch function have totally wrong parameters. For example, parameter in the position samples{k} change to 'audiorecorder object'.

It seems that I do not know exact use of 'StopFcn' & 'TimerFcn'.

Is there anyone who can give me some advice? I really appreciate all of your comments.

Comment: This is the same question as your last post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520290/how-can-i-use-function-callback-stopfcn-timerfcn-for-audiorecorder-objec, you should remove one of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [example in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/audiorecorder.getaudiodata.html) I would recommend trying to call getaudiodata(r) in your loop rather than with the CallBack. So something like this:

```
% assume fs,winsize,winshift is given.

T = 0.1; % in seconds
samples = cell{100,1};
r = audiorecorder(fs,16,1);
k=1;
r.TimerPeriod = 0.1;
r.StopFcn = 'disp(''Completed sample '', k)';
r.TimerFcn = {@get_pitch,samples{k - 1},winsize,winshift};

while 1
     record(r,T);
     samples{k} =  getaudiodata(r);
     k=k+1;
end
```

Note I changed the `r.TimerFcn` to use `samples{k - 1}` instead of `k` because k will increment before the timerfcn gets called. So this might give you issues with your first sample, you'll have to tweak it a little. Also this is an infinite loop, which I'm sure you'll want to address.